# PHP connection to Redis

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am using phpredis to connect to Redis server (https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis). I have written a very basic redis client for my app, which should simply take env parameters and connect to redis server. My redis client looks like follows:

```
<?php

use \Redis

class Redis
{
    /** @var Redis */
    private $redis;


    /**
     * @param RedisServer $redis
     * @param string $redisHost
     * @param string $redisPort
     */
      public function __construct(RedisServer $redis, string $redisHost, string $redisPort)
      {
          $this->redis = $redis;
          if (!$this->redis->connect($redisHost, $redisPort)) {
              throw new ConnectionException('Failed to connection to redis server', 500);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Close connection when Redis service is destroyed
       */
      public function __destruct()
      {
          $this->redis->close();
          $this->redis = null;
      }

      //....

}
```

Do I need to explicitly close Redis connection in __destruct()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you are my man :) Yes and no! using __destruct() is the secure way to be save (like in java) to be/have the connection closed. in php this works different. remote connects (like db, fs...) will be closed befor the custom destructor is called. But for the future: keep this up! Its a correct way and "bootdown" not a bottleneck, yet :)